# unable to start uiautomatorviewer in windows due to classpath error

Tags: java, android-studio, appium, android-uiautomator, uiautomatorviewer

I am unable to start uiautomatorviewer due to below error:

```
C:\Users\176226\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin>uiautomatorviewer
-Djava.ext.dirs=..\lib\x86_64;..\lib is not supported.  Use -classpath instead.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

I have added all the needed paths for tools, cmd-tools and platform tools and android_home in env variables

below are details of java version used. Can uiautomator be used without having to downgrade java version:

```
openjdk version "17.0.2" 2022-01-18 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu17.32+13-CA (build 17.0.2+8-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Zulu17.32+13-CA (build 17.0.2+8-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Appreciate help

Comment: I changed java version to : C:\Users\176226>java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0-262"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-262-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.71-b10, mixed mode)...But still have same issues

Answer (score 1):

this was a real adventure....

1. download and install specifically JDK version 8 (not JRE or any other version)
   https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase8u211-later-archive-downloads.html
2. add JDK8 to your environemnt path as `JAVA_HOME`..for example:
   [image]
3. make sure `%ANDROID_HOME%\tools\bin` is also added to your `Path` as well so that you can run `uiautomatorviewer` from any directory
   [image]
4. in terminal, run `uiautomatorviewer`